# How to change the time of Sojourner medal?

Tags: ingress

In ingress I can hack along all the day. So the sojourney medal was not a problem, but in a few weeks I will be able only to hack in the morning, between 8.00am -10.00am.

The problem is that my sojourney count to me at 19.30/45 more or less and  I don't want to loose the day.

My question is: How can I "move" the count time to the morning (8.00/10.00 am) without loose the medal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer to your question would be:
You can not move the count time (unless you restart the streak from 0). But hacking at 19.30/45 and then 8.00am-10.00am next morning and every morning after that will keep your medal moving.

To elaborate:

- To keep your badge going, hack whenever you can. And never let there be 24h between hacks. You can put a timer when you finish the day.
- The counter will increase (internally) every day at the fixed time (for me that is 10h20 in the morning). Stats will be updated by the first hack after that time. But that does not mean that I need to hack then. If I hack every afternoon, in the morning Ingress will be ready to update my stats and it will be updated in the afternoon when I do my first hack. Just no more than 24h between hacks.

Imagine that there is a sand clock that you reset every time you hack- if you pass 24h, repressions will start. If you reset it every 23h (by hacking), life is great! If you hack every 5 minutes, keep it up and have a great game!

Comment: thanks! now I thing I understand :D hope I can "move" my counter time ^^

Answer (score 6):

You misunderstand how the Sojourner medal works. It is *not* based on a fixed time every day, but it requires that you complete a hack less than 24 hours after your previous hack.

Hence you just need to make sure you hack at both 08:00 and 10:00 every day, and you'll be fine - just ensure that your *first* hack every day is before your *last* hack on the previous day.

Comment: Ok, so lets supose... I do my last hack today (in my hour zone) at 19.45 (so the Sojourner counts to.. 89? is today ? :p ) Then, tomorrow I only do a couple of hacks (more or less between 8.30/9.30am) and 14.00 (dinner time ^^ ) and nothing will change. Then I do again the hack in 2 days again at morning (same hours) And its suposed that my counter will raise to 90 and will be "moved" to that windows time (8.00/10.00 am). All that comes due work and connection issuess I'll have in few weeks

Comment: There is no "window". It's based purely on making a hack less than 24 hours from your previous hack.

Comment: Although the 24 hour cycle is absolutely the safest path to follow, I have accidentally missed a hack and had about 27-28 hours between hacks without the badge resetting, so there is something more going on there.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ingress, the working of Sojourner medal is that it counts the last hack made on that day.So if your last hack was made at 11 pm you need to hack it before 11 pm the next day to keep the streak going.